# How do I find out in iOS if an XML file from URL is unencrypted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was thinking to have a category on NSXMLParser with one class method (BOOL)isUnEncryptedXML: and in the implementation try to initialise a local instance of NSXMLParser using its initWithContentsOfURL:
The assumption is, if it won't initialise, it can't read the XML, so it is not unencrypted.

Would you find such an implementation naive? Is it reliable in the context of my question?

Comment: Suggestion: Just provide a method to check for encryption and if so decrypt. A  `Category` is just combining two unrelated things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do 2 things.

1. an xml file has to begin with `<?xml`
2. an xml file that is encrypted likely won't parse. So try parsing it and if it isn't well formed the parser will fail

If 1&2 fail then the file is invalid :encrypted / broken
If only 1 fails, then you could **ASSUME** it is encrypted

you can't really tell encrypted/broken by looking at the xml